# Specifying the opacity on fadeToggle

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to use **fadeToggle()** but specify the opacity it goes down to, instead of having the element disappear?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$("#toc li").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
        $("#toc li").not(this).stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

---

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#toc li").hover(function( e ){
    $(this).siblings('li').stop().fadeTo(400, e.type=='mouseenter' ? 0.4 : 1);
});
```

or invert the logic `1 : 0.4` depends on what you need.